# have a scrolling table, want to start at the bottom of the scroll?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery scorlling table which is populated dynamically. I am using [Bob Craven's jquery scroll solution](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/01/html-scrolling-table-with-fixed-headers-jquery-plugin/).

What i want is when the page loads the table should be at the bottom, also when a new row is added dynamically this should be where the focus is.

After the Script is applied it created div's around the table...this is the source code:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; border: 0px solid rgb(136, 136, 136);" id="placeordetb_table_wrap">
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;" id="placeordetb_head_wrap">
<table style="table-layout: fixed;" class="placeorder_items" id="placeordetb_head" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 160px; overflow: auto;" id="placeordetb_body_wrap">                     <table class="placeorder_items" id="placeordetb" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
       <tr valign="top">    
        <th>Line number</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Profile</th>
        <th>Inner</th>
        <th>Outer</th>
        <th>Length</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Line Value (Net)</th>
        <th></th>
       </tr>
       <tr id="10">
       <td>10</td>
       <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
       <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>6.5</td><td>1</td>
       <td></td>
       <td><a href="javascript:deleteRow(1029,10)">Delete</a></td></tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
</div></div>
```

normal:

```
<div  class="placeorder_item">

<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="placeorder_items" id = "placeordetb" >
<tr valign="top">   
<th>Line number</th>
<th>Notes</th>
<th>Profile</th>
<th>Inner</th>
<th>Outer</th>
<th>Length</th>
<th>Unit</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Line Value (Net)</th>
<th></th>
</tr>

<tr id="10" >   
<td>10&nbsp;</td>
<td  style="text-align:center;">
    </td>
<td>etc010&nbsp;</td>
<td>1002M&nbsp;</td>
<td>1003&nbsp;</td>
<td>6.500 &nbsp;</td>
<td>L6.5&nbsp;</td>
<td>1&nbsp;</td>
<td>62.52&nbsp;</td>
```

Delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method to dynamically handle the scrolling:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scrollBottom = Math.max($('#placeordetb').height() - $('#placeordetb_body_wrap').height(), 0);
    $('#placeordetb_body_wrap').scrollTop(scrollBottom);
});
```

See the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/xbMBW/2/) for an example.

Comment: Does the demo work for you, at least? Unfortunately, I can only get it working with the HTML you provide, and wouldn't really know why it's not working in page. Is there a public URL for your working copy that you could append to your question?

Comment: had to move the code down after i applied create scroll...thanks